# Instagram Embeds: Data isn't in sync with real time Instagram Data

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I just noticed that instagram embeds on my site aren't showing the correct number of likes and comments of the actual instagram post.

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm- 
permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/BwrRM1Bhw_F/" data-instgrm- 
version="12" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box- 
shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; 
max-width:540px; min-width:326px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit- 
calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:16px;"> 
<script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script> </backquote>
```

find the embedded code
https://jsbin.com/fupusonufo/1/edit?html,output

Link to instagram post : https://www.instagram.com/p/BwrRM1Bhw_F/